# Permission Check Code Snippet for an ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a permission check code snippet in each page in my application like below,

```
<% 
int permission = Int32.Parse(Session["userpermission"].ToString());
if (permission != 1) {
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}

%>
```

So if it is not equals 1, then it will redirect to Login Page, but now i need to add permission = 2 also into this condition in a specific page, where both permission levels 1 & 2 can enter, but I tried using OR operator "|" inside if condition like (permission != 1 | permission != 2), but then neither both permission levels can enter the page, Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking whether the permission doesn't equal `1` *or* doesn't equal `2` will always be true.
After all, no possible number can equal both `1` and `2`, so it will always be equal to one of them.

You want to check whether it is unequal to `1` **and** also unequal to `2`.

Comment: what I need to do is, for this page if the permission level = 1 or 2 then, the user should be able to see the page, but i don't need to put the whole HTML inside an IF Statement.

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra: What part of my answer don't you understand? You need to understand how boolean logic works.

Comment: Do you mean to use 'AND' instead of 'OR' ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good design practice to authorize a user. The future maintenance will be nightmare.

Ideally, you want to use Role based authorization.

If you cannot implement Role base authorization, you can at least use a **BasePage**, and inherit all xxx.aspx.cs from the **BasePage**.

```
public partial class Default : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int permission = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userpermission"] ?? "0");
        if (permission == 1 || permission == 2)
        {
            // User is authorized, so allow access.
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the logic like this. I personally do not like it because it is hard to read.

```
if (permission != 1 && permission != 2)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```